# Issue with Radio Button on R Shiny CRUD app

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an survey and I am referring this [Shiny CRUD app](https://gist.github.com/gluc/d39cea3d11f03542970b) on github, this works fine until I have a question with radio button.

in UI have a new input fields

```
radioButtons("Question1","Question1", choices = c("Y","N","NA"),inline=T),
```

I changed the CRUD functions as below, to accommodate the above input field

```
    # Cast from Inputs to a one-row data.frame
    CastData <- function(data) {
      datar <- data.frame(name = data["name"], 
                          used_shiny = as.logical(data["used_shiny"]), 
                          r_num_years = as.integer(data["r_num_years"]),
                          Question1 = data["Question1"],
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      rownames(datar) <- data["id"]
      return (datar)
    }

    # Return an empty, new record
    CreateDefaultRecord <- function() {
      mydefault <- CastData(list(id = "0", name = "", Question1 = "Y",used_shiny = FALSE, r_num_years = 2))
      return (mydefault)
    }

    # Fill the input fields with the values of the selected record in the table
    UpdateInputs <- function(data, session) {
      updateTextInput(session, "id", value = unname(rownames(data)))
      updateTextInput(session, "name", value = unname(data["name"]))
      updateCheckboxInput(session, "used_shiny", value = as.logical(data["used_shiny"]))
updateRadioButtons(session, "Question1",value = unname(data["Question1"]))
      updateSliderInput(session, "r_num_years", value = as.integer(data["r_num_years"]))
    }
```

when I run I get error "*Warning: Error in updateRadioButtons: unused argument (value = unname(data["Question1"]))*"
unable to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`radioButtons` doesn't have any parameter called `value` you probably want to use `selected` instead!

Hope this helps!